# How to get list of active smart-contracts on EOS

Tags: smart-contract, cleos

It appears cleos has no way of returning a list of active smart-contracts. Is there another way?

Answer (score 2):

Most accounts with smart contracts deployed on the mainnet would have `abi` info provided. With `mongo_db_plugin` of `nodeos`, you could list all accounts with `abi` field in mongodb.

```
db.accounts.count({abi: {$exists: true}})
```

Current result is 1858.

Comment: Thanks. How did you do this query? Is there a way to do this using cleos?

Comment: @Kabir You need to setup a nodeos instance with mongo_db_plugin enabled, and then query that mongodb instance.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a snapshot of the accounts available, you can do `cleos get code ACCOUNT_NAME`. If the result is zero, then the account has no smart contract attached to it. Otherwise it does. Loop through all the accounts and sum all the ones with non-zero code hashes.